# Custom accessor for record's generic component

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a record with a custom accessor for a generic component? I get a compilation when I try:

```
java: invalid accessor method in record SearchResult
  (return type of accessor method results() must match the type of record component results)
```

Here's the code:

```java
public record SearchResult<T>(String nextPageId, List<T> results) {

    public SearchResult {
        requireNonNull(nextPageId);
    }

    public List<T> results() {
        return unmodifiableList(results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue, [check this online demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/nyV) using Java 17

Comment: I know this is an old question, but would you happen to be using Corretto? I think there's a bug in their compiler